# W/System: A resource failed

Tags: java, android

**My Logcat is filled with these warnings:**

> W/System: A resource failed to call destroy
>
> W/System: A resource failed to call close
>
> W/System: A resource failed to call release

How can i identify the cause of these warnings? Logcat isn't giving much information about it.

Comment: Did you find any more information regarding this?

Comment: @MrinmoyMk If you're using an emulator, try using a real device because i noticed that i'm not getting these messages on my real device.

Comment: I am already using a real device

Comment: @MrinmoyMk does is also show the message when you open other apps like eg. Play Store? Because when i open other apps it also shows these messages.

Comment: @MrinmoyMk I think you can just ignore these messages because every app i open they show these message. Just make sure if you're using something like a Cursor Object to close it when you're done with it

Comment: Ok thank you. I will just the message for the time

Comment: @Vince Did you get any solution?

Comment: This turns out to be the same as this question stackoverflow.com/a/63386527/1864688 (not immediately obvious due to slightly different message--turns out the message is generated programmatically). I've posted an answer there about how to get more diagnostic info.